# NFS, Quota and LDAP

Tags: debian, ldap, nfs, openldap, quota

I have the following scenario in two servers with Debian:

**Server #1**
OpenLDAP, NFS exporting /home

**Server #2**
PAM with pam_ldap configured to authenticate against Server #1, `/home` directory mounted via NFS in Server #1.

The users authenticates in **Server #2** via SSH.

Now I need to configure user quotas, installed quota package and mounted `/home` with usrquota and grpquota (Server #1). I have loaded quota.schema in the LDAP server, and every user has the attribute `quota: /home,softlimit,hardlimit,softinode,hartinode`

How I can make this quota effective? Doing repquota /home on Server #1 doesn't show this limits. I am missing something to configure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

afaict repquota doesn't activate the quotas. it's quota.on 's job. make sure you created the quota.group and quota.user files at the root of the fs.
also remember that some filesystem (xfs) use different mount options for quota activation.

maybe this will help you:

http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/47